# I can't detect a file movement under docker with angular

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-mac

my dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY app/package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY app/ /app/
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And my docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  angular:
    build:
      context: ./MehdiAppFront
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: angular
    volumes:
      - ./MehdiAppFront/app/src:/var/www/usr/src/app/src
      - /src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
```

I've tried all the solutions I know of but nothing works, I'm really lost.
I take help to chat gpt, but he don't know.

Comment: What do you mean "file movement?" What are you trying to do? What's the expected behavior vs what you are seeing?